# Multiple Configuration Files Per Target

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode I am able to assign a single xcconfig file to my project and targets:

[image: Target selection]

Is there any way to assign more than one xcconfig file to a target? In the dropdown it only allows a single selection.

I understand that I am able to override build settings from my project configuration file in my target configuration file, I'm up against a problem where I may need to have separate configuration for environments (dev, QA, prod) and separate configurations for different "flavours" of the app so being able to have multiple configuration files per target seems like a potential solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configuration files support the `#include` statement so you could build your higher-level files from one-or-more lower-level files.